# IE 11 Javascript Object doesnt support property or method 'match'

Tags: javascript

Its a javascript countdown its working on Firefox & Chrome but not working on IE 11. Here is the code

```
return this.each(function() {
  // Convert
  if(!(toDate instanceof Date)) {
    if(String(toDate).match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
      toDate = new Date(toDate);
    } else if( toDate.match(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})\s([0-9]{1,2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})/) ||
        toDate.match(/([0-9]{2,4})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\s([0-9]{1,2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})/)
        ) {
      toDate = new Date(toDate);
    } else if(toDate.match(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})/) || 
              toDate.match(/([0-9]{2,4})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})/)
              ) {
      toDate = new Date(toDate)
    } else {
      throw new Error("Doesn't seen to be a valid date object or string")
    }
  }
```

Comment: The Regex `match` method has been there since [JavaScript 1.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) so it is HIGHLY unlikely that it doesn't exist in `IE`, though I'm not in a position to tell.  More than likely, `toDate` is not getting parsed correctly and is either `null` or `undefined.`  Use the debugging tools or `console.log` to check it's value.

Comment: I have the same problem. And I tried so many ways. A help will be more than welcome.

Comment: I think it's regex syntax that's not working. You need to use `new Regexp("string without forward slashes")`